# Calculation of "model coordinates" for GRASS m.nviz.image

Tags: grass-gis, nviz

I'd like to be able to derive the x,y model coordinate for the `position` parameter of `m.nviz.image` ([manual](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/m.nviz.image.html)) from a projected (e.g., UTM) coordinate on the map representing the position of the viewer.

I've looked through the source code but I'd prefer not to try to reverse-engineer the formula (assuming there is one), especially because there seem to be some magic numbers in there.

So, is there a standard way to do this?

Added context: I've built a script that renders animations featuring a DEM, an ortho overlay and several raster and vector components. There are about 20 scenes. Using the model coordinates for the viewer position is fiddly, so I'd like to be able to extract them from the map as projected coordinates and transform on-the-fly to model coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to answer my own question (provisionally), the solution *is* linear and just involves some scaling and translation.

Here, `region` is the computational region set in GRASS (a tuple containing W, N, E and S bounds).

- `gs_unit_size`, `rng` and `rng_off` mirror the `GS_UNIT_SIZE`, `RANGE` and `RANGE_OFFSET` constants in `ogsf.h` and `nviz.h`.
- `longdim` is the larger of the width and height of the region (`GS_get_longdim` in `ogsf.h`).
- The meat of the function is from `gsd_real2model` in `gsd_views.c`.

In Python:

```
# Constants.
gs_unit_size = 1000.
rng = 5. * gs_unit_size
rng_off = 2. * gs_unit_size

# Get the region dimensions (map units).
w = abs(region[2] - region[0])
h = abs(region[3] - region[1])

# The longer dimension.
longdim = max(w, h)

# Scale factor (used for both x and y).
scale = gs_unit_size / longdim

# Calculate the 'real' coordinate.
mx = (px - region[0]) * scale
my = (region[1] - py) * scale

# Calculate the model coordinate.
dx = (mx + rng_off) / rng
dy = (my + rng_off) / rng
```

In this instance, `my` is calculated this way because I'm using UTM, and the northing increases upwards in the Northern hemisphere.